# Breaking down an average in a nonlinear function into its contributing components

Tags: numerical-methods, average

Originally I was given a moving average that I had to break down to its proportions and display, so business analysts could anticipate the impact of the first element in the average being dropped (i.e. A bar chart being able to see how significant the first element is to the total when making decisions)

$ result = \dfrac{x+y+z}{3}$

$ proportion_x = result \cdot \dfrac{x}{x+y+z} $

Such that $ proportion_x + proportion_y + proportion_z = result $

However, this average is now logarithmically normalized before the final output:

$ result = \left(\log \left(\dfrac{x+y+z}{3}+ 10\right)-1\right)\cdot 10$

Is it still possible to produce this component breakdown for $x, y,$ and $z$ accurately now that the relationship is non-linear?

Comment: How accurate do you want the component breakdown?

Comment: @eyeballfrog is it not possible to solve precisely? In terms of accuracy, I'm sure a 5% margin of error is acceptable since we're just seeing the relative magnitude of the element being dropped

Comment: It might be possible to solve precisely, but there's a good chance of nasty transcendental functions involved. Also, to be clear, if we call the result of the log normalized average $\mu_\ell$, you want some set of values $p_x, p_y, p_z$ such that $p_x + p_y + p_z = \mu_\ell$ and they each correspond to roughly how much each variable contributed to $\mu_\ell$?